# convert latitude and longitude to northing and easting in java?

Tags: java, latitude-longitude

how to convert latitude and longitude to northing and easting in Java?

Comment: northing and easting from what point? Are you using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system , or just what?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean UK OSGB easting and northings. The trigonometry behind this one is hilarious, but you can use the [JCoord](http://www.jstott.me.uk/jcoord/) library for this, it makes it easy (if quite CPU intensive).

---

To follow up on @DD's comments below, there is a gotcha with JCoord, in that you have to make sure you're using the correct datum when converting from Easting/Northing to Lat/Long, and vice versa.

Take @DD's code:

```
LatLng latLng = new OSRef(394251,806376).toLatLng();
```

This will return a Lat/Long which uses the OSGB36 datum, i.e. the "flat earth" approximation used on UK maps. This is substantially different to the WSG84 datum used in most applications (including Streetmap), which models the world as a sphere (more or less).

In order to convert to a WGS84 lat/long, you need to make it explicit:

```
LatLng latLng = new OSRef(394251,806376).toLatLng();
latLng.toWGS84();
```

This will adjust the lat-long to the correct datum.

Note that the [javadoc](http://www.jstott.me.uk/jcoord/api/1.1-b/uk/me/jstott/jcoord/OSRef.html#toLatLng%28%29) for `OsRef.toLatLng()` is very clear about this:

> Convert this OSGB grid reference to a latitude/longitude pair using the OSGB36 datum. Note that, the LatLng object may need to be converted to the WGS84 datum depending on the application

Conversion between coordinate datum is not simple. If it looks simple, you're likely doing it wrong.

Comment: JCoord was a complete waste of time....The accuracy is terrible. I compared it to several other online tools and it was out by over 30.

Comment: @DD: Are you going to leave it at that rather unhelpful remark, or give some useful information?

Comment: @skaffman that was an accident...pressed carriage return and it entered the comment....I dont want anyone wasting time with this library...its not accurate and I've wasted a few hours with it.

Comment: @DD: I've built many location-critical apps using JCoord, and I've found it to be highly accurate.  It is, however, slightly fiddly to use properly, and it's likely that you're not using the API correctly.  So rather than simply saying "it's useless", how about showing me some sample code that demonstrates this?

Comment: @skaffman...am I using it wrong? looked incredibly easy to use!

Comment: PostCode "AB101AA" Easting=394251 Northing=806376 {new OSRef(394251,806376).toLatLng()} returns 57.14841674744993, -2.0950248639315605 vs streetmap.co.uk/streetmap.dll?GridConvert returns 57.148232, -2.096648

Comment: Code "LatLng latLng = new OSRef(394251,806376).toLatLng(); latLng.toWGS84();" returns  Lati [57,148235] Long[-2,096648].

Answer (score 4):

Try GeoTools:

```
       CRSAuthorityFactory crsFac = ReferencingFactoryFinder
    .getCRSAuthorityFactory("EPSG", null);

    CoordinateReferenceSystem wgs84crs = crsFac
            .createCoordinateReferenceSystem("4326");
    CoordinateReferenceSystem osgbCrs = crsFac
            .createCoordinateReferenceSystem("27700");

    CoordinateOperation op = new DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory()
            .createOperation(osgbCrs, wgs84crs);

    DirectPosition eastNorth = new GeneralDirectPosition(easting, northing);
    DirectPosition latLng = op.getMathTransform().transform(eastNorth,
            eastNorth);


    double latitude=latLng.getOrdinate(0);
    double longitude=latLng.getOrdinate(1);
```

---

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I know this is old but it does literally the opposite of what the asker was looking for. And if you're going to take answers from elsewhere, its nice to [cite](http://ageeksnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/convert-easting-northing-to-latitude.html).

Comment: Simply switch the order of the two reference systems in the .createOperation() call and you have the conversion the OP asked for. But agree with @ozliftoff, not cool to pass off others' work as your own.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel like pulling in GeoTools and you discover JCoord is no longer available in Maven central, there's a small library for converting OSGB (UK's Easting/Northing) into WGS84 from DSTL: https://github.com/dstl/osgb

Adapted from the README:

```java
import uk.gov.dstl.geo.osgb.Constants;
import uk.gov.dstl.geo.osgb.EastingNorthingConversion;
import uk.gov.dstl.geo.osgb.OSGB36;

// ...

//Convert from Easting and Northing into Cartesian Coordinates (LatLon)
double[] latlonOSGB38 = EastingNorthingConversion.toLatLon(
      new double[]{ easting, northing },
      Constants.ELLIPSOID_AIRY1830_MAJORAXIS,
      Constants.ELLIPSOID_AIRY1830_MINORAXIS,
      Constants.NATIONALGRID_N0,
      Constants.NATIONALGRID_E0,
      Constants.NATIONALGRID_F0,
      Constants.NATIONALGRID_LAT0,
      Constants.NATIONALGRID_LON0);
 
//Convert from LatLon (OSGB) to WGS84
double[] latlonWGS84 = OSGB36.toWGS84(latlonOSGB38[0], latlonOSGB38[1]);
```