# Different results using JCoord and GeoTools

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, geotools

I have been trying to covert Easting and Northing values to lat/lon using JCoord and GeoTools. Problem is I am getting different results for each library using the same Easting & Northing.

The code I am using is the code provided in the main answer and GeoTools answer provided in this question.
[convert latitude and longitude to northing and easting in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313618/convert-latitude-and-longitude-to-northing-and-easting-in-java)

The easting I am using is : 393339

The Northing I am using is : 806179

The coordinates Jcoord is providing are (57.14645296506957, -2.111**6**98674790966)

The coordinates GeoTools is providing are [57.146449494619105, 2.111**7**14868502565]

They seem to lose accuracy around the 4th digit and I'm wondering which one is right??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that these are OS Eastings and Northings (which seems likely based on your lat/lon values) then they are accurate to 1m (as 6 figure grid references). Based on the values given by [this calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html) a degree of latitude is around 100 km so the 4th decimal point is roughly 10m or about the accuracy you can expect.

To get more precision out of the calculation you need to make sure of the ToWGS84 parameters being used in each calculation - for GeoTools you can query the projection to find this value, I expect JCoord has a similar operation.

Note in GeoTools the towgs parameter may vary depending on which referencing factory you are using, I believe that gt-epsg-hsql is more accurate than the gt-epsg-wkt.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes they are both set to ToWGS84 so I'm guessing it must be something to do with the referencing factory. I'll experiment when I have a bit of time. Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually a 6 figure grid references is only accurate to ~10m (see https://support.landmark.co.uk/entries/45135813-National-Grid-Reference-Coordinate-Conversion), so any lat/long value after the 4th decimal place is redundant. That said if you rounded the values to 4 decimal places in the example above you would still get (slightly) different latitude values (57.1464 vs 57.1465).